# Type aliasing and dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing, new-operator

I'm trying to facilitate automatic vectorization by the compiler in the blitz++ array library. For this reason, I'd like to present a view of the array data that is in chunks of fixed-length vectors, which are already vectorized well. However, I can't figure out what the type aliasing rules imply in conjunction with dynamically allocated arrays.

Here's the idea. An array currently consists of

```
T_numtype* restrict data_;
```

Operations are done by looping over these data. What I would like to do is present an alternative view of this array as an array of `TinyVector<T_numtype, N>`, which is a fixed-length vector whose operations are totally vectorized using the expression template machinery. The idea would be that a L-length array should be either `T_numtype[L]` or `TinyVector<T_numtype, N>[L/N]`. Is there a way to accomplish this without running afoul of the type alasing rules?

For a statically allocated array, one would do

```
union {
  T_numtype data_[L];
  TinyVector<T_numtype, N>[L/N];
};
```

The closest I could think of is to define

```
typedef union {
  T_numtype data_[N];
  TinyVector<T_numtype, N>;
} u;
u* data_;
```

and then allocate it with

```
data_ = new u[L/N];
```

But it seems that now I have given up my right to address the *entire* array as a flat array of T_numtype, so to access a particular element I would need to do `data_[i/N].data_[i%N]`, which is a lot more complicated.

So, is there a way to legally create a union of `T_numtype data_[L]` and `TinyVector<T_numtype, N>[L/N]` where L is a dynamically determined size?

(I'm aware that there are additional alignment concerns, i.e. N must be a value that is the same as the alignment of the TinyVector member, otherwise there will be holes in the array.)

Comment: What do you mean by "a dynamically determined size"?

Comment: Like I say, I want to allocate it with `new`.

Comment: So are you asking if a member of a union can be dynamically allocated? Your original question seems to indicate you are doing something quite ambitious, but I get a feeling you know very little about C++ - but I could be wrong.

Comment: If the goal is to reinterpret the raw array as a TinyVector, this is one of those areas a where a `reinterpret_cast<>` is exactly what the doctor ordered. Either you play foul to squeeze the last drop of performance, or you play safe and accept the cost. There no having it both ways. I feel a union is higher acrobatics that add unnecessary complexity; the TinyVector would have to match the memory layout of an array directly. There is really no reason to make this that hard. You can keep TinyVector open and just hard-alias (reference) the array's storage region?

Comment: Yes, reinterpret_cast'ing to a TinyVector would work -- I've done this before. However, since this code is going into a general-purpose library, I'd like the code to be standards-compliant if possible.

Comment: Neil - Actually, I have a lot of experience with C++. The issue here is more one of unions and C, which I use considerably less. I guess "dynamically allocating a union member" is one way to phrase it, but my long-winded question was to give some background. The one sentence version of the question would be: "Is it possible to use a union to alias two dynamically allocated arrays of different objects just like it is with single objects?"

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing is hard to make legal. However, if some "operations are done by looping over these data.", do those operations require that these data are exactly an array of T_numtype?

It may be better to wrap the data in a class with one data member of type `TinyVector<T_numtype, N>[L/N]` or even `std::vector<TinyVector<T_numtype, N> >` since that L is apparently determined at runtime, and expose a pair of iterators for those operations  that want to loop over the entire data as a single sequence.